# Understanding relationship between repo layout and final install location

Tags: python, setuptools

## Question

**I'd like to have a better sense for the types of "transformations" that Python modules and packages living on a developer's machine could possibly go through, starting during development time and ending after installation (when they're in `site-packages`)**

**By "transformation", I mean a file living at one location during development, say `/foo/bar.py`, and ending up in a different location after installation, say `/bar.py`.**

I don't intend to enumerate all possible protocols or transformations, but the more I dig into Python packaging and distribution, the more confused I get. I'd love to have a concise roadmap that I can use to dig deeper.

*For context: I'm working on a tool that, given line execution traces using `sys.settrace`, I can determine which dependency a file (& line number) originated from (since that's what `sys.settrace` provides me). I'd like to come up with an algorithm to map absolute filepath to dependency (& version). So if there's an easy way to do that, I'd actually appreciate this as an answer. But my current approach is to just dig deep into Python packaging and distribution and learn how it works.*

### My current understanding

I divide this up into "build" and "installation".

#### Package build

From my understanding there are a bunch of "build systems" that a developer might use to package their code. `setuptools` and `distutils` are a few tools that I run across when I do a Google search. Each of these seems to have its own way to describe the various files that live in the package (`setup.cfg`, `pyproject.toml`, ..) and how to transform them into a bundle.

For one example:

```
[options]
package_dir = = src
```

This directive (setuptools) will have the effect of "pulling everything in src up one directory level", since it searches for packages inside of `src`.

It seems like I'd have to learn each of the packaging tools and all of the directives that transform file structure to gain a good understanding of where files "live" once they're packaged.

#### Package installation

Once the project is packaged and living on some host waiting to be used, I don't have a good understanding of what happens when it is installed. For example, when I run `pip install`, do additional transformations occur before the files end up in `site-packages`?

### Final thought

I'm hoping this question makes sense. Having never packaged or distributed a Python project, I'm not even sure if I'm asking the question in the right way. I'd really accept any "answer" that provides a bit of clarity to me as I continue my research.

Comment: Regarding your actual question: you want to query dependency name given a path to its module? For the installation question: if the dependency provides a wheel file, `pip install` is merely an extraction of a zip archive into site packages. If the dependency provides a source dist, `pip install` is unpacking the source dist, building a temp wheel and extracting it into site packages. No transformations are applied to module files - the file in site packages is identical to the one zipped in wheel.

Comment: @hoefling ah this is really helpful. I didn't know that. Thank you!